# AWS Lex not identifying response if by a variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Response of below lambda code is not accepting by lex, but in **return** statement if I change json **slots** value as **slot** variable declared, then working i.e response of it accepting by lex. Its full confusing because variable **slot** and variable **d** has same value, please find my cloud watch log screenshot attached FYI.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    slot=event['currentIntent']['slots']
    d="{'Intro': None, 'Start': None, 'ReturnBooking': None, 'name': None, 'pickup': None, 'conformation': None, 'location': None, 'Count': None, 'comfort': None}"
    print("using dict:",slot,"using variable:",d)
    return {  
       "dialogAction": {
   "type": "Delegate",
   "slots": d
  }
          }
```

[image]

Please help me if any one figured out.

Answer (score 3):

If a slot is not holding a value, then it should be `null` not `None`. It looks like Cloudwatch is logging `null` as `None` for you. And that should be the difference between your variables: `slot` and `d`.

So this is what `d` should be:

```
d="{'Intro': null, 'Start': null, 'ReturnBooking': null, 'name': null, 'pickup': null, 'conformation': null, 'location': null, 'Count': null, 'comfort': null}"
```

But there's really no reason to recreate a string for the slots of your intent. You should simply pass the `slots=event['currentIntent']['slots']` variable back to Lex. And if you want to change a slot in Lambda, treat it like an array and set one of the slots to a new value:

```
slots['slotName'] = "new value";
```

Or you can remove a slot's value by setting it to null:

```
slots['slotName'] = null;
```

Then return `slots` back to Lex.